# Can a Piecewise Linear Regression Approximate a Neural Network?

Tags: neural-networks, piecewise-linear

I have a piecewise linear regression model that performs quite well (CVd) on subsets of a small data set (Ns between 30 and 90 for the subsets, with a total of 222 records).

So there are separate models for each subset of the records -- with different variables in each, and different weights for variables that appear in multiple models.

In addition, the original variables were segmented into sub-variables using loess plots and familiarity with the data.  (This was done intuitively -- I didn't discover piecewise linear regression or the related R packages until recently.  I expect the results may be improved by more precise segmentation.)

Anyhow, neural nets could do absolutely nothing with the data.  (Possibly due to the # of weights vs the sample sizes?)

So what I'm trying to get my head around is whether my model (the four sub-models considered as a whole), with localized variable selection and localized variable weights, represents an approximation of what a neural network might find if there were enough data to build a good one?  Or is that the wrong way to think about what's happening?

In other words, how is subsetting the records and segmenting the variables like/not like a neural network?

I apologize if my terms are loose or vague -- as I'm sure is apparent I'm not a statistician.

Comment: Could you edit your post and go into more detail about the neural network you used? It's architecture, weight initialization, optimization method, etc?

Comment: Thanks for asking Indie.  I had a chance to show this to a stats PhD with a lot of NN experience and he got interested enough to work on that piece himself for a fair bit of time.  So unfortunately I don't know exactly what all he tried.  He seemed to think a NN should improve the results, but nothing beat the baseline error.  I'm not really trying to get a NN to work at this point though -- I'd just like to understand if what I've done approximates one.

Comment: Do you have the Dataset on GitHub ? I want to have a look!